# How to unescape string html in my var in form raw function twig?

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I would like to unesacpe chars in my variable `help` below, but i can't encode it in `form_raw()`

I tried this way :

```
{% set help %} {% include 'front/partials/help-bubble.twig' %} {% endset %}

{% autoescape false %}
     {{ (form_row(form.password.first, {
         label: transcap('password') ~ help
      }))|raw }}
 {% endautoescape %}
```

Thx for help ;)

Answer (score 1):

Don't escape the whole thing, try to only the escape the variable you want to escape

```html
{% autoescape false %}
     {{ (form_row(form.password.first, {
         label: (transcap('password') ~ help)|raw
      })) }}
 {% endautoescape %}
```